# Android Studio WebView image upload

Tags: javascript, android, android-layout, android-activity, webview

How can I load the photo of my apps I each site that already programmed for the mobile?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.xmple.com");
}
```

Comment: are  you looking for only a image from the web?

Comment: I just want to upload image from my apps when I click on record to my site and I click on image not charge me for nothing

Comment: To upload the image you can use this code https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples/blob/master/input-file-example/app/src/main/java/inputfilesample/android/chrome/google/com/inputfilesample/MainFragment.java

Comment: hello I do not know where I'm going to put code because they are not practical

Comment: It's for uploading files through WebView, if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: and too hard for me to put the code together with my code :D help me pls